# Generating image from many divs overlay

Tags: jquery, canvas

I have a main div which has many sub divs and these sub divs have img tags that has a sub image which are overlayed with each other on that main div and creates a main image. Is there any way i can actually get the image of the main div, which is the overall image of all the img tags? Any jquery plugin to do that? Any advice is appreciated ! thanks!

I tried with the canvas tag but the img tags inside are not showing. the html is as below

```
<canvas id="shirt_display">      
     <img src="'.base_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/'.$collection[$num].'/SBase1.png" data-type="Base">
     <img src="'.base_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/'.$collection[$num].'/CollarInner.png" data-type="Inner Collar Back">
     <img src="'.base_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/'.$collection[$num].'/CollarOuter.png" data-type="Inner Collar Front">
      <img src="'.base_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/Button/B_Black/ICollarB.png" data-type="Inner Collar Buttons">
      <img src="'.base_url().'marcella-resources/front/img/Button Holes/BH_Black/ICollarBH.png" data-type="Inner Collar Button Holes">
</canvas>
```

I create a click event to test whether i can fetch the image or not. My jquery is as below

```
$('.test').click(function()
{
    var canvas=document.getElementById('shirt_display');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    window.open('', document.getElementById('shirt_display').toDataURL());
})
```

Comment: Hard to follow. I'd like to help, but I need a little bit more clarity of what you are looking for. One main image or somehow get a snapshop of all the images put together that 'creates' a visual display on the page, and you want to capture that? Just a bit confused. example somewhere?

Comment: can you use html5?? if yes then I've a easy solution

Comment: @james emanon get a snapshot of all the images put together at the javascript side and save it to database or something like that.

Comment: @Manish if its html5, is it canvas?

Comment: obviously..you can place multiple img tags in the canvas, properly position them, and then u can canvas.ToDataUrl('image/png;base64'); and then use it anywhere else or store it in db

Comment: if img tags inside are not showing that simply means, your calculated url to them, didn't get calculated, so why don't you do this: write a function which executes on document.ready and you create new img tag through javascript, and you calculate src in some variable, and then assign it to the img, and then add it to the canvas. that's what i did for testing out your prlbm.

Comment: hmm can explain what you mean by the calculated url did not get calculated? because when i check the network and inspect those img tags  are actually loaded. but on the page its not shown